# Phone number sequence entered is not correct in Angularjs (tested on chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, mean-stack

I am developing an Mean stack application where I take phoneNumber input in this format (333)999-9999 in a  textbox from the user.
When I enter input on other then chrome its sequence is correct like if I enter `(041)899-8999` it will show same in text box.

But when I use `Chrome` its sequence shown in text box is like `(041)989-9999` it only happening on `chrome.`

Angular.js code of view is

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 margin-bottom">         
<input type="tel" class="form-control text-box-complaint" 
id="telephone" name="telephone"
placeholder="Contact Phone (713) 456-7890" 
ng-focus="clear_messages()" 
ng-model="formData.telephone" 
ng-pattern="/^(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}$/"
required="" 
ng-maxlength="14">
```

And controller.js is like for phone

```
 $("#telephone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
 $('input, textarea').placeholder();
```

Comment: can you provide a plunkar?

Comment: @GauravSrivastava i didn't made this application, SO dont know about flow . I just know its view code and controller. maybe problem is in type or anything